# Regular expression to keep a running count of individual characters

Tags: regex, r

Consider the following vector `x`

```
x <- c("000a000b000c", "abcd00ab", "abcdefg", "000s00r00g00t00")
```

Using a single regular expression, I'd like to keep only those elements of `x` that contain more than three letters.  Here are the rules:

1. The letters are not always consecutive (this is the main issue)
2. The string elements of `x` can be of any number of characters
3. There will be nothing in the string except digits and lower-case letters

The simple way I thought of would be to remove everything that is not a letter and then take the number of characters, something like the following.

```
x[nchar(gsub("[0-9]+", "", x)) > 3]
# [1] "abcd00ab"        "abcdefg"         "000s00r00g00t00"
```

I know that there are statements like `[a-z]{4,}` that finds four or more consecutive lower-case letters.  But what if individual letters are scattered about the string?  How can I keep a "running count" of letters such that when it passes three, it becomes a non-match?  Right now all I can think of is to write `[a-z]+` a bunch of times, but this can get ugly if I want to match say, five or more letters.

This gets me there, but you can see how this could be ugly for longer strings.

```
grep("[a-z]+.*[a-z]+.*[a-z]+.*[a-z]+.*", x)
# [1] 2 3 4
```

Is there a way to do that with a better regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this where `\\D` matches a non-digit, `.*` matches a string of 0 or more characters and `(...){4}` says to match four times, i.e. more than 3.

```
grep("(\\D.*){4}", x, value = TRUE)
```

This will match if there are 4 or any greater number of non-digits.  Just replace 4 with 6 if you need more than 5.  If its important to have the number 3 in the regexp then try this pattern `(\\D.*){3}\\D` instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is a repetition operator you can use: `{n}` matches the previous token or group `n` times. To make matches more efficient, you should also be specific in what may be matched between letters (in your case only digits, not "any" character (which the dot `.` matches)):

```
^(?:[0-9]*[a-z]){4}[0-9a-z]*$
```

matches all strings that contain at least 3 lowercase letters.

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?:       # Start of a (non-capturing) group:
 [0-9]*   # Match any number of digits
 [a-z]    # Match one lowercase ASCII letter
){4}      # Repeat the group exactly four times
[0-9a-z]* # Then match any following digits/letters
$         # until the end of the string
```

In R:

```
grep("^(?:[0-9]*[a-z]){4}[0-9a-z]*$", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);
```

gives you a character vector with all the elements that are matches by the regex.

Comment: Is it important that it's a non-capturing group?

Comment: @GSee: It's marginally more effective. Capturing a submatch (and then overwriting it with each repetition) when it's not needed later on anyway slows the regex engine down unnecessarily.

Comment: I think the right word would have been "efficient", not "effective".

Answer (score 3):

The below grep command would find the elements which has four or more letters

```
> grep("^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){4}", x, perl=T, value=T)
[1] "abcd00ab"        "abcdefg"         "000s00r00g00t00"
```

OR

```
> grep("^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3}[^a-z]*[a-z]", x, perl=T, value=T)
[1] "abcd00ab"        "abcdefg"         "000s00r00g00t00"
```

To find the elements which has 5 or more letters,

```
> grep("^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){5}", x, perl=T, value=T)
[1] "abcd00ab" "abcdefg"
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?:                      group, but do not capture (4 times):
  [^a-z]*                  any character except: 'a' to 'z' (0 or
                           more times)
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
){4}                     end of grouping
```